# React: How to get API data from one component and pass it to another

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to pass data from my search bar component which returns a JSON from an API call to another component that will display the information. I am having a lot of trouble figuring it out. I tried making a container that holds both of the components and pass the data. Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks!

My Search Bar Component

```
class SearchBar extends Component {
constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
}
handleSubmit(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    let reqBody = {
      name: this.refs.name.value
    };
    fetch("/api", {
      method: "POST",
      body: JSON.stringify(reqBody),
      headers: {"Content-Type": "application/json"}
    })
      .then((res) => {
        if (res.ok){
          return res.json();
        } else {
          throw new Error ('Something went wrong');
        }
      }).then((json) => {
        console.log(json)
        this.props.onDataFetched(json)
      })
  }


  render() {
    return (
  <div >
    <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
    <input placeholder = "Enter Name" type="text" ref = "name"/>
    <button type ="Submit"> Search</button>

    </form>
  </div>
    );
  }
}
```

The component that displays the

```
class History extends Component {
    render() {
    return (
      <div >
        <h2> History</h2>


         <ul>
          <li>
          //display data here 

          </li>


         </ul>



      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

My container component

```
class Container extends Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state ={
            history : []
        }
        this.handleResultChange = this.handleResultChange.bind(this)
    }
    handleResultChange(history){
        this.setState({
            history,
        })
    }

  render() {
    return (
      <div >
        <SearchBar onDataFetched={this.handleResultChange}/>
        <History data={this.state.history}/>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: It's better call API inside the container. You can send the search param to the container and doing the Api call there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can handle the form submit in the search component in the itself. Pass the search value(input value) to the container component.

```
class SearchBar extends React.Component {
constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
}

handleSubmit(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    let reqBody = {
      name: this.refs.name.value
    };

    console.log(reqBody);
    this.props.onDataFetched(reqBody);
}


  render() {
    return (
  <div >
    <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
    <input placeholder = "Enter Name" type="text" ref = "name"/>
    <button type ="Submit"> Search</button>

    </form>
  </div>
    );
  }
}

class Container extends React.Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state ={
            history : []
        }
      this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this)
    }

    handleChange(searchValue){
        console.log(searchValue);
    }

  render() {
    return (
      <div >
        <SearchBar onDataFetched={this.handleChange} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
ReactDOM.render(<Container />, mountNode )
```

Now saying that the ideal way to do this would be as mentioned above by using redux and redux forms.

https://redux.js.org/

https://redux-form.com/

This will help you save a lot of time in the future as you will have a correct structure to do it.

Comment: is it possible to pass the JSON I get to lets say the component that displays the data or should I just do it in the container ?

Comment: do the fetch from the container using the search value, the same fetch call you did in the search component,Keep the values in the state and pass it onto the listing component that you have as a property. 

Passing the entire search result json from Search component to the container component would be an overkill i feel, so do the fetch in the container.

Comment: ok thanks that worked. The input passed from the search and I was able to get the data from the API. What would be the best way to send the data I got from the container to the list component

Comment: As specified above pass the same on as a property to the listing component.When the above is alrite have a look at Redux as well.

Answer (score 1):

I would really suggest you to take a look to [redux](https://redux.js.org/basics/usage-with-react), it will make your development easier and it's almost a standard implementation for this cases.

Comment: Thanks I will definitely look into redux